# Get sum of array and callback a function inside another function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, methods, callback

I am trying to solve a problem where I have to get the sum of an array using the .reduce() method inside a function and instead of returning the sum, I need to invoke the callback and pass the sum there.

I am pretty sure I am using the .reduce() correctly but I keep getting 'undefined' and, for the life of me, I cannot figure out how to get invoke a function inside a function.

Any help/explanations would be greatly appreciated!

Question: Sum up all of the integers in the numbers array.
Instead of returning the sum invoke cb and pass in the sum there.

My code:

```
function sumArray(numbers, cb) {
  //code here

  numbers.reduce(function(sum, currentValue) {
    return sum + currentValue;
  }, 0);

  cb([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], result);

}

function addTwo(num) {
  const result =  num + 2;
}
```

Comment: Where do you even call `sumArray()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question says

> Instead of returning the sum invoke cb and pass in the sum there.

means `cb(sum)`, nothing more. With this callback one could do other stuff.

Here is an example:

```js
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function sumArray(numbers, cb) {
  var sum = numbers.reduce(function(sum, currentValue) {
    return sum + currentValue;
  }, 0);
  cb(sum);
}

function outputSum(sum) {
  console.log("The sum is " + sum);
}

function addTwo(sum) {
  console.log(sum + 2);
}

sumArray(numbers, outputSum);
sumArray(numbers, addTwo);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is, I assume, your homework so I don't want to give too much away but here are a couple pointers.

`numbers.reduce(function(sum, currentValue) {` is calculating the sum but then not storing it. You want something like `var reduced = things.reduce(...)`.

Also `cb` is probably expecting to be passed just 1 argument, the sum, where as you are currently passing an array as the first argument and `result` (which you haven't declared yet) as the second argument.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the problems
1. Your reduce() function needs to return its output to your result variable. You did not return the output to the result variable and you did not define the result variable.
2. If the addTwo() function is the callback function, then you are supposed to pass in a single variable. But since you did not indicate the destination of the cd call back, I guess you did not include it in the code sample. Do this;

```
function sumArray(numbers, cb) {

 var result=numbers.reduce(function(sum, currentValue) {
    return sum + currentValue;
 }, 0);

 cb([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], result);

}

function addTwo(num) {
 const result =  num + 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I guess you must be trying to do something like that.

1. You must to store the reduce return.
2. You must return the callback function.

To have access to the internal callback you must return the callback.

```js
function sumArray(numbers, cb) {
  //code here
  let result = numbers.reduce(function(sum, currentValue) {
    return sum + currentValue;
  }, 0);

  return cb([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], result);

}

function sumTwo(arr, num) {
 return  Number(num + 2);
}

console.log(sumArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], sumTwo));
```